# Excel Pivot Slicer & Unique List in one Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

What I wanted to achieve is to get Unique values list (Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4) in one column (same as on picture 2) so that I can have it for Slice and Dice when using Pivot Tables/Charts. I wanna have "Y's" on one slicer so I can click corresponding attribute to compare it..
I mananaged to do that using Power Query, but it is hard to explain to someone PQ when they are lack of knowledge, at least in my Company..they wanna have it simple as a day.

This is data set without PQ:
[image]

And this is what I did with PQ and actually how it should look like:

[image]

So my question is, is there some neat and nice way to write this in functions or else? But simplified..

QUERY CODE:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"X", Int64.Type}, 
{"Y1", Int64.Type}, {"Y2", Int64.Type}, {"Y3", Int64.Type}, {"Y4", 
Int64.Type}}),
#"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"X"}, 
"Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "Index", 1, 1),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "X", 
"Attribute", "Value"}),
#"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Custom", 
each if [Attribute] = "Y1" then "Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 " else "Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4", type 
text),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Conditional Column", 
"Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Custom.1", 
"Custom.2", "Custom.3", "Custom.4", "Custom.5"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter", 
{{"Custom.1", type text}, {"Custom.2", type text}, {"Custom.3", type text}, 
{"Custom.4", type text}, {"Custom.5", type text}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Custom.5"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Custom.1", 
"Y1"}, {"Custom.2", "Y2"}, {"Custom.3", "Y3"}, {"Custom.4", "Y4"}}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Y1", "Y2", 
"Y3", "Y4"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed 
Columns1"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"},#"Table3 
(2)",{"Index"},"Table3 (2)",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table3 (2)" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table3 
(2)", {"Attribute", "Value"}, {"Attribute", "Value"})
in
#"Expanded Table3 (2)"
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and add your query text from PQ Advanced Editor?

Comment: @FlexYourData I did copy coding part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query looks OK as it is. I also think you should continue to persevere with PQ. As people become familiar with it, they will learn to trust it and exploit it. This will be good for them, for your company and ultimately, for you as the Power Query Guy!

I think you can just stop after the 'unpivot other columns' step. For your pivot table, put [Attribute] in the Columns area and [Sum of Value] in the values area. You can then use your slicer to slice in the same way, but your query result will be more intuitive to outsiders.

Of course, you don't *have* to show the query output. You could show the data as it is originally, but when choosing Close & Load To from the Power Query Editor, just select "Pivot Table Only" and put the pivot table next to the blue source data table. That way, the people in your company won't be asking questions about the weird green table with the unfamiliar column names. Or worse, try to edit the query output!

Tell them they can edit the blue table, then refresh the pivot table. That's it.

Comment: I think you are actually right..why to complicate life when there is no need. I will stick to it...and thx for suggest, I deleted rest of the steps, same thing =)